# How to append new model to view in backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js

On adding new model to my collection I don't want the view to be refreshed but I want the model to be appended to my collection and be appended to the view. SO i shouldn't render the view again. Is it possible via Backbone.js? How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a view that handles the whole layout, and a view that represents a single model. You would make the render method of the latter to return the HTML of a single model, and append the result to a list using the main view. You have a great example of this in the Addy Osmani's book ["Developing Backbone.js applications"](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#application-view). Take a look at the section where he explains how he renders each task to the todo list of his Todo App, if I understood well, your problem is solved in there.